# Redirect_to in model after error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect

I have a function in my model to import data from a CSV file and I'd like to have validations should there be any errors.  For example, when I upload the file, I search for a `User` based on an ID in the file.  If there is no `User` with that ID, I'd like to `redirect_to` a different page with an error.

```
def self.getUser(scale_id)
    @user = User.find_by(scale_id: scale_id)
    if @user == nil
        redirect_to users_path
    else
        return @user
    end
end

def self.bulk_upload_weigh_ins(file)
    output = []
    errors = []
    CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true, ) do |row|
        row = row.to_hash
        @scale_id = row["scale_id"]
        @user = getUser(@scale_id)
        row.merge!(user_id: @user_id)
        WeighIn.create! row.to_hash
    end
end
```

...and no matter what path I put there, I get the following: `undefined local variable or method 'users_path' for #<Class:0x007fa06f466998>` even when it is a valid path.

**Is there something wrong with redirecting like this?  If yes, how should I do it?**

Comment: Path helpers are not available in models unless you specifically include them. They should not be specifically included; models should be as agnostic as possible, and should not have specific knowledge about the web side of things. Also, it's probably a good idea to follow Ruby conventions and name the method `get_user`... but I'd go further and say the method is named incorrectly. And you'd be setting a class-level instance variable in your model--you should return a local `user` instance, and not using a class-level instance variable. IMO this doesn't deserve a method of its own.

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way for custom validations is to do something like:

In your model:

```
User < ActiveRecord::Base

validate :get_user

def initialize(params={})
   self.id = params[:id]
end

def get_user
  @user = User.find_by(self.id)
    if @user.nil?
        errors.add(:base, "Invalid User")
        return false
    else
        return @user
    end
end
```

In your controller you'd then do:

```
def whatever_action_youre_using
   @user = User.new(user_params)
   unless @user.valid?
     redirect_to users_path
   end
end


def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :email, :etc, :whatever_your_atts)
end
```

Comment: I should have been clearer in my question, I will add more to make my real question understood

Answer (score 0):

> I have a function in my model that is searching for a User based on an
>   ID
>
> undefined local variable or method 'users_path' for
>   Class:0x007fa06f466998

As ***@Dave Newton*** mentioned in the comments, the ***path helpers*** are not available in models unless you specifically include them. Also you can't and never need to use `redirect_to` in a ***model***. The application logic should be moved to the controller. Something like below should work

```
def get_user
  @user = User.find_by(scale_id: params[:user][:scale_id])
  if @user.nil?
    redirect_to users_path, notice: 'Your error message here'
  else
    return @user
  end
end
```

Comment: I'm not sure why the CSV import function is in the model .  I was following a RailsCast episode, but it seems that everything would run smoother if I kept it in my controller